# .htaccess : 404 on uploaded images

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel

i'm using laravel 5.0 on my server. i've just uploaded some images to my public/uploads folder.

But when i try to access them eg. /uploads/image.jpg, i'm receiving a **404 Not Found** error.

Additionally my firefox browser says "**Page is not redirecting properly**" when i try to access just the "/upload/" folder(where i think it should be saying 403 forbidden or something).

how can i solve this problem? heres my .htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem for "The page isn't redirecting properly" is the follwoing line in your code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

change it to this line :

```
RewriteRule ^/$(.*) /$1 [L,R=301]
```

the other code works fine for me .